# Abstract algebra T/F questions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

This is from our review and my study group is wondering if we can get some feedback on our progress:

---

$1$. The symmetric group $S_3$ only has two proper normal subgroups.

True, because $e \subset A_3 \subset S_3$.

$2$. Every abelian group is cyclic.

False, every cyclic group is abelian but the converse is not true OR a counter example is a Klein-4 group.

$3$. The ideal generated by $x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is maximal.

True. Every ideal generated by irreducible element in principal domain is maximal.

$4$. The order of the cycle $(a_1, \cdots, a_k) \in S_n$ is $k$.

False. The order should be $k-1$.

$5$. Let $f: R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism, and $I \subset S$ a maximal ideal. Then $f^{-1}(I)$ is maximal.

True. Because isomorphism preserves ring properties (honestly no idea how to do this one).

---

Comment: The order of a $k$-cycle is indeed $k$.  Also, inverse images of maximal ideals need not be maximal.  Consider the zero map between two fields, noting that the unique maximal ideal of a field is $\{0\}$.  Inverse images of prime ideals, however, are always prime.

Comment: For 5, consider the embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Jared He might mean unital rings, in which case the zero map is not a homomorphism.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: You're right.  $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ is a better example.

Comment: @Tobias I hope you don't mind that I used your example!? I was composing my answer when I saw your comment, and your counter-example was MUCH better than the one I had in mind!

Comment: @amWhy Not at all.

Comment: For 1, you have shown that $S_3$ has *at least* two proper normal subgroups. Why aren't there more? For 2, the fact that every cyclic group is abelian is irrelevant. Just give a counterexample (the one you mention is good).

Answer (score 2):

Three for five isn't bad: but you need to also show there are *at most* two normal subgroups in $S_3$.

$(4)$ Note that the order of a cycle in $S_n$ is the length of its cycle, which in your case, is $k$. (More generally, the order of a permutation expressed as $k$ disjoint cycles is the least common multiple of the *lengths* of the disjoint cycles.)

$(5)$ And the inverse image of a maximal ideal is not necessarily itself maximal. As @Tobias just posted, consider the embedding of $\mathbb Z$ into $\mathbb Q$. (Note also that the question was about a ring **homomorphism**, not an *isomorphism*, which you mention in your reasoning that follows.)